# How can find ListBox which is in a template?

Tags: wpf

on a toggle button. I have written a pop-up and in this popup, there is a list box. how can I access this from code behind? I have tried with `FindName` but no use

**Tried:**

```
 var something=  btnTLanguage.FindName("LstBTLanguage");

var uiElement = (ToggleButton)btnTLanguage;
var toggleButton = uiElement.Template.FindName("LstBTLanguage", uiElement);//no use
```

**This is my style**:

```
 <StackPanel Name="sta" Background="Transparent">
    <ToggleButton Name="btnTLanguage"  >
        <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Popup  IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=btnTLanguage}" VerticalOffset="1" HorizontalOffset="0"  >
                                    <Border Background="White" >
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <ListBox DisplayMemberPath="VALUE" SelectedValuePath="KEY"  Name="LstBTLanguage" Width="Auto"  IsEnabled="False" >

                                            </ListBox>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </Popup>
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ToggleButton.Style>
    </ToggleButton>
</StackPanel>
```

Useage:

```
FrameworkElement obj;
 TryFindCildElement(sta, "LstBTLanguage",out obj);
```

Comment: That's the reasom. I wrote you should wait for the Loaded event. In the constructor register an event handler: this.Loaded += OnLoaded; In this handler perform the search. Please try it yourself. Then it will work.

Comment: for guys looking for ans after the visual tree is constructed this will work means if u r calling in ctro, it won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`VisualTreeHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper?view=netframework-4.8) to search the tree for the `ListBox`.
The key is to check if the cild element is a `Popup`. Since `Popup` doesn't host its children directly, we would have to unwrap the child by accessing the `Popup.Child` property.

Second you have to wait until the `Window` or `Page` is `Loaded` (subscribe to `Loaded` event.

Search the `FrameWorkElement` by name:

```
ListBox listBox = this.btnTLanguage.Template.FindName("LstBTLanguage", this.btnTLanguage);
```

or

```
private bool TryFindCildElement(DependencyObject parent, string elementName, out FrameworkElement resultElement)
{
  resultElement = null;
  for (var childIndex = 0; childIndex < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); childIndex++)
  {
    DependencyObject childElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, childIndex);

    if (childElement is Popup popup)
    {
      childElement = popup.Child;
    }

    if (childElement is FrameworkElement uiElement && uiElement.Name.Equals(elementName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
      resultElement = childElement as FrameworkElement;
      return true;
    }

    if (TryFindCildElement(childElement, elementName, out resultElement))
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Example:

```
FrameworkElement listView;
if (TryFindCildElement(this.btnTLanguage, "LstBTLanguage", out listView))
{
  // Element found
}
```

Search the element by type (first occurrence):

```
private bool TryFindCildElement<TElement>(DependencyObject parent, out TElement resultElement) where TElement : DependencyObject
{
  resultElement = null;
  for (var childIndex = 0; childIndex < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); childIndex++)
  {
    DependencyObject childElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, childIndex);

    if (childElement is Popup popup)
    {
      childElement = popup.Child;
    }

    if (childElement is TElement)
    {
      resultElement = childElement as TElement;
      return true;
    }

    if (TryFindCildElement(childElement, out resultElement))
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Example:

```
ListBox listView;
if (TryFindCildElement(this.btnTLanguage, out listView))
{
  // Element found
}
```

Comment: yes, of course. You can pass in any element. that extends `DependecyObject`.

Comment: its not working sorry im not able to find the popup

Comment: i mean this (childElement is Popup popup) is not hitting

Comment: No. `VisualTreeHelper` is available from .NET 3.0 on.

Comment: this the way i have used its giving me null result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196882/discussion-between-avinash-reddy-and-bioniccode).